# In js when returning a reference to a this value vs passing the this reference keyword, is there a difference in binding time?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the below code which prevents bugs caused by a function silently passing to a call back function more arguments that aren't wanted in the parameters of the callback function:

```
["1","2","3"].map(parseInt)
```

returns `[1, NaN, NaN]` because the index gets passed as a second parameter to parseInt which accepts it as the radix, so the array values are invalid. To solve it, the author of [this blog post](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/166) suggests a js extension:

```
Function.prototype.only = function(numberOfArgs) {
   var self = this; //the original function
   return function() {
      return self.apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments,0,numberOfArgs))
   }
};
```

Which would be called like so:

```
["1","2","3"].map(parseInt.only(1))
```

I'm struggling to understand why "this" is passed as a function parameter while self is returned as a reference to this. They both point to parseInt correct? Is there a difference in binding times of parameters vs return values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm struggling to understand why "this" is passed as a function parameter while `self` is passed as a reference to `this`. They both point to `parseInt` correct?

No. `self` will refer to `parseInt`. `this` will be whatever `this` the function was called with, which could be anything. In your example:

```
["1","2","3"].map(parseInt.only(1))
```

...`this` will either be a reference to the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode), because `map` will use `undefined` when calling the callback (which is turned into a reference to the global object in loose mode).

There are several ways `this` might be something else though:

1. If a second argument were passed to `map`:

   ```
   ["1","2","3"].map(parseInt.only(1), {})
   // Second argument -----------------^^
   ```

   ...it would use that value rather than `undefined` when calling the callback.
2. If `Function#bind` were used on the function `only` returns:

   ```
   ["1","2","3"].map(parseInt.only(1).bind({}))
   // Bind ---------------------------^
   ```

   ...then `this` would be that value.
3. If the function `only` returns were called with `call` or `apply` (which is what `map` does, so this is kind of a repetition of #1 :-) ), the value supplied for `this` would be used.

Answer (score 2):

> They both point to parseInt correct?

No.

[The value of `this` depends on how a function is called.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

The function passed to `map` gets called by the internals of `map`.

Look at [the documentation for `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be used as callback's this value. Otherwise, **the value undefined will be used as its this value**.

So if the returned anonymous function used `this` instead of `self` it would be calling `undefined.apply` not `parseInt.apply`.